# Import a folder with files inside into a jailbroken iPhone using vb.net

Tags: ios, iphone, vb.net, jailbreak

I am writing an app in **VB.NET** *(Visual Studio 2013)* and as a final step, it has two copy a folder (with several files inside) into a certain directory in an iPhone.

The iPhone is **jailbroken** so it is possible to access every kind of directory and it should also be connected to the PC via USB. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you how you would do this programmatically:

First, you need to tunnel SSH over USB. You can do that by programatically executing itunnel_mux.exe from [this zip.](https://code.google.com/p/iphonetunnel-usbmuxconnectbyport/downloads/detail?name=itunnel_mux_rev71.zip&can=2&q=)(you'll have to extract everything first.) Use it like this:

```
itunnel_mux.exe --tunnel -iport 22 -lport 2222
```

Then, you can use SCP (I'd recommend [this library](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_dotnet)) to Copy files over from root@127.0.0.1:2222 (password alpine).

This is some example pseudocode:

```
'Extract the exe and dll file from that zip
extract_files()
'I'm making a new variable containing the port number. 
Dim port As string = "2222"
'I made up this function. Lets pretend it executes Batch code in the current directory (like a bat file)
execbat("itunnel_mux.exe --tunnel -iport 22 -lport " + port)
Using scp As New Rebex.Net.Scp
    ' connect to a server
    scp.Connect(hostname)
    ' authenticate (change alpine if you changed your root passwd)
    scp.Login("root", "alpine")

    ' Here, you can use "scp" to upload and download files
    scp.PutFile("C:\Users\KevinKZ\Desktop\fileToUpload.jpg", "/var/mobile/Documents/fileToUpload.jpg")
    scp.GetFile("/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db", "C:\Users\KevinKZ\Desktop\SMS_Backups\2-1-14.db")
    scp.Disconnect()
End Using
```

This solution is far from elegant. It also requires OpenSSH (I think). You might be better off using libimobiledevice.

Comment: I think this is the best solution that could have been offered. Yes, most jailbroken iPhones have OpenSSH installed (otherwise the program could notify them to install that first). I know about libimobiledevice but I couldn't get started with it (the problems you have when you migrate from VB6 to the latest version of VB.net)

Answer (score 0):

If the directory is accessible from Windows then yes.